# Why is my java code not sending data to firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

So I'm building an Android app that adds users to the Firebase database from a form inside the Register Activity.

I'm building this in Android studio 3 and already ran it on my HTC One M9

```
package com.example.mobilniproekt;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
                EditText lastname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastname);
                EditText city=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.city);
                EditText email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
                EditText username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
                EditText password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

                String id=databaseReference.push().getKey();
                User user=new User(id, name.getText().toString(), lastname.getText().toString(), city.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(), username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());

                databaseReference.child(id).setValue(user);

                name.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However when I launch the app, fill out the form and check my database there isn't any data.

Am I implementing the code wrong or is there another problem with the Firebase configuration?

Comment: Try to add a complete listener and log the message. What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user first for them

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                   FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Or if they already have account, they need to sign in first with their details

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                } 
                 else {
                    Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Then you can send to firebase whatever data to write

Comment: I assume in the email and password parameter I put in my google account email and password right?

Comment: It depends on what are you doing. From the data on your form it seems that you are collecting data per user, so ideally the login will have the user's email and password, so you need to use the email and password from this form, or separate form to register first, up to you, this will create account for the user, which will help you later on who have access to what parts of the database

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the help. However I should mention that I have authentication disabled for my database so I don't think that that's whats causing the problm

Comment: Alright. In this case, you might need to check if your app is allowed to access the database. If you go to your firebase console, you should see a little droid on the bottom left corner of your project

Comment: Added another answer to show what I mean, I will leave this answer as it might be helpful for others

Comment: Yes it has allowed access

Answer (score 0):

Check if your app is allowed access to your firebase[image]